# Частичные методы

Tags: c#

Изучаю С#.И вот дошел до темы "Частичные методы". 3 раза прочитал эту тему но я не могу понять о чем хочет мне сказать это книга. Если знаете ответьте пожалуйста простым объяснением(как то  сомневаюсь),или же примером кода.

Только не ругайте, пока тестирую с консолью.
Вопросы, которые трогали меня :

> 1)Частичные методы могут быть
> статическими, но всегда являются
> приватными и  не могут иметь
> возвращаемого значения. Любые
> используемые в них параметры не  могут
> быть параметрами out, хотя и могут
> быть параметрами ref. С ними не может 
> применяться ни один из следующих
> модификаторов: virtual, abstract,
> override,  new, sealed и extern

(почему ?, должен же на чем то все это основываться).

> 2)почему у частичных методов не может
> быть  возвращаемого типа?

(почему всегда void?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частичные методы обычно используются кодогенераторами. Они объявляются в автоматически сгенерированной части кода и оттуда же вызваются, а в части кода, которая пишется вручную, их можно реализовать. Если метод не реализован, при компиляции его вызовы автоматически удаляются из кода. Соответственно, сигнатура этих методов должна быть такой, чтобы их удаление никак не повлияло на собираемость кода. Отсюда описанные ограничения.

Comment: Это partial?? омг зачем же все переводить)